# Redirecting domain to subdomain with htaccess on a Wordpress network

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble redirecting my domain to a subdomain.

My domain is www.example.com and I want all traffic to go to aa.example.com. I've got my domain (www.example.com) and subdomain (aa.example.com) as two sites on a network in Wordpress.

I tried the following code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

After setting the redirect I can't access my network dashboard because an endless loop has been created, and I can't access my domain (www.example.com/wp-admin) dashboard because it redirects to the subdomain dashboard.

Is there another way I can create the redirect without encountering these problems?

Answer (score 1):

I think the loop is because WordPress url is set to your website url ( www.yourwebsite.com )
Here is how to fix this : 
1.Go to your .htaccess file then delete the redirect code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

1. Go to www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin > settings > General and then set your website url to subdomain.yourwebsite.com
2. add the redirect code again to your .htaccess file .

Comment: Don't worry you always can re-change your website url using the Database

Comment: Thanks, but there's no such setting in that location ... nor in the network settings

Comment: Yes there is . You are using WordPress right? 
check out this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/9xBMh8P.jpg

Comment: Definitely not there. I think this option might be removed when you set your Wordpress up as a network http://imgur.com/gEtzZXN